# Margin (vertical space) of the first block after a text node?

Tags: html, css

**First question:**

Inside a block such as `<dd>` or `<td>` or `<li>`, am I right in saying that either or both of the following would be normal and correct?

```
<td>
  An introductory sentence as a text node.
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</td>
```

And/or:

```
<td>
  <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</td>
```

---

**Second question:**

Assuming that's so, what CSS can I use to ensure that in both cases there's a margin between the two sentences, but not before the first sentence?

My problem is that if I do something like ...

```
td > p { margin-top: 1em; }
```

... this works correctly when the first sentence is a text node, but it puts an unwanted margin between the first sentence and the containing `<td>` when the first sentence is inside a paragraph.

I would want a solution that works even when the first sentence contains an inline element, such as `<strong>` or `<a href="...">`.

---

In summary CSS should produce the *same* layout, as follows, for *both* of the two HTML examples:

```
-- top of <td> here
-- no margin here
-- first sentence here (whether it's a text node and/or inside a <p>)
-- margin here, between the two sentences
-- second sentence here inside a <p>
```

---

**Third question:**

If it's true that it's not possible to define a CSS rule which creates the same format for both kinds of HTML, then I guess that web site authors must be careful to always use only one HTML markup?

If so, which you do suppose it normal?

- **Never start a block with another block, always start it with a text node** (then you could use the CSS rule which says that the first block should have a `margin-top`); for example, do this:

  ```
  <td>
    An introductory sentence as a text node.
    <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  </td>
  ```

  This wouldn't work though if for example the first thing in the block is meant to be a list -- the list would have unwanted `margin-top`:

  ```
  <td>
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
  ```
- **Never start a block with a text node, always start it with a block** (then you could use the CSS rule which says that the first block shouldn't have a `margin-top`); for example, do this:

  ```
  <td>
    <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
    <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  </td>
  ```

  That's more markup than I expected though. I think I'm used to seeing markup like `<li>List item</li>` rather than `<li><p>List item</p></li>`
- Don't standardize, use either, but add extra `class=` or `style=` attributes to blocks as necessary, to add or remove a top margin on a case-case basis.

Comment: Re question 3: there's no 'normal' way. Developers use whatever meets requirements. Use will vary among developers and projects.

Comment: Having margin between paragraphs seems to me a "normal" requirement, so I was hoping for a normal solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if you would consider this to be a complete answer to your question, as I'm aware you are using a `<td>` in your examples and one difference between the `<td>` and `<dd>` or `<li>` elements is the fact that `<td>` elements can't be offset against their surrounding elements without breaking their `<table>` specific behaviour. But at the very least I can answer a part of your third question:

> If it's true that it's not possible to define a CSS rule which creates the same format for both kinds of HTML...

That isn't true, you can always render a floating `:before` pseudo element with a `width` of  `100%;` set, and setting half the `margin` of the sibling `<p>` elements on it.

```css
dd {
  border: 1px dashed lightblue; /* this line is for demonstration purposes only */
}

dd:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  An introductory sentence as a text node.
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</dd>
<dd>
  <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</dd>
```

This introduces an empty "dummy" paragraph, which only affects direct text nodes of the `<dd>` as the `<p>` elements will just perform [their automatic margin collapsing magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) instead of moving downwards. I think this proves that it is at least possible to define a CSS rule which creates the same format for both kinds of HTML.

Here's how this works, or at least how I understand this to work. The W3C has an example in the CSS spec which shows us that the text node in the question must be an [anonymous block box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level), because it is a text node rendered inside a box with `display: block;` set, the `<dd>`, and it has a sibling with `display: block;` set, the `<p>`.

By adding the pseudo element - which is rendered inside this anonymous block box (it must be, because otherwise it would never be able to behave like an inline element, or else it may be rendered as two [anonymous inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous), without the containing block box) - but in any case, we end up with two anonymous inline boxes (the pseudo element and the text node).

The next step is to get the first of these anonymous inline boxes, the pseudo element, and take it out of the normal flow by floating it left, then setting its `width` to `100%`, and making it take up a height which matches the height of the sibling `<p>`'s margin (which I accomplished by setting a margin of half the `<p>`'s margin, but you could do the same by setting a height or bottom margin matching the `<p>`'s margin).

Now the preceding text node has an artificial top margin. The question remains, why does this not affect the `<p>` elements if there is no preceding text node? I think that's because - since there is no preceding text node - the pseudo element is itself rendered as an empty anonymous block box inside the element on which it is applied (as pseudo elements with content always render inside the element on which they are applied), which is essentially the same as rendering an empty `<span>` element before the `<p>`.

Here's a proof of concept:

```css
dd {
  border: 1px dashed lightblue;
}

span {
  float: left;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

dd:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  <span></span>
  <p>
    The dashed light blue line marks the paragraphs margin box, the light grey box is the span.
  </p>
</dd>
<dd>
  <p>
    The dashed light blue line marks the paragraphs margin box, the light grey box is the pseudo element.
  </p>
</dd>
```

This "artificial margin" is a left floated block box (anonymous block box in case of the pseudo element) inside its containing element. All other block boxes will move down if they need to (as they are supposed according to the [W3C floating spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) when the floated box doesn't leave any space for them), this only happens as the floating box starts to outgrow the margin in which it is hiding, and it doesn't happen in the solution to this specific problem, as I have specifically set the artificial margin to be exactly as high as the actual margin of the `<p>`'s.

I think the secret lies in this part of the W3C floating spec, which is a little hard to follow:

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.
>
> A line box is next to a float when there exists a vertical position
>   that satisfies all of these four conditions: (a) at or below the top
>   of the line box, (b) at or above the bottom of the line box, (c) below
>   the top margin edge of the float, and (d) above the bottom margin edge
>   of the float.
>
> Note: this means that floats with zero outer height or negative outer
>   height do not shorten line boxes.
>
> If a shortened line box is too small to contain any content, then the
>   line box is shifted downward (and its width recomputed) until either
>   some content fits or there are no more floats present. Any content in
>   the current line before a floated box is reflowed in the same line on
>   the other side of the float. In other words, if inline-level boxes are
>   placed on the line before a left float is encountered that fits in the
>   remaining line box space, the left float is placed on that line,
>   aligned with the top of the line box, and then the inline-level boxes
>   already on the line are moved accordingly to the right of the float
>   (the right being the other side of the left float) and vice versa for
>   rtl and right floats.

I would understand this to mean "non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist", so the `<p>`s, which are non positioned block boxes should not be affected by the floating box.

But that's not what it means. Instead it states that, when the box is floated left, a line box is created to the right of the floating box, filling the space between the right side of the floating box and the right side of the containing box. And inside that line box lives the block box which is the succeeding `<p>` element. And if that `<p>` element could fit in the space which satisfies the four conditions mentioned, it would sit next to the float in the line box.

Since the float is set to a width of `100%`, the `<p>` doesn't fit next to the floated box, and it, sitting inside its line box, moves down to the next line, where it somehow magically decides to partly honour the first part of the rule: "non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist", which only seems to be true for the margin, because as soon as the float box outgrows the margin, the block box does start to move down, maybe because its sitting in a line box as well..

Now for anything except a `<td>` tag it would be quite trivial to have the added space on top disappear as it can easily be done by offsetting the element containing the content against its containing element.

```css
dd {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1em;      
}

dd:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  /* everything below this line is for demonstration purposes only */
  border-top: 1px dashed lightblue;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <dd>
    An introductory sentence as a text node.
    <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  </dd>
</div>
<div>
  <dd>
    <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
    <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  </dd>
</div>
```

Which I think answers the second question, at least for `<dd>` and `<li>` elements, even allowing for inline elements in the preceding text node.

If you wanted to do that inside a `<td>` you'd have to start managing the `<td>` or `<table>` height some other way, as you'll have to use absolute positioning inside the `<td>` and break the default table behaviour where the table grows with its content by setting the table cell to `display: block;` (or by rendering an additional `<div>` inside the `<td>` and using that as the block level element, but that would also break the default cell growing behaviour).

```css
table
{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

dd {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1em;
}

dd:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px dashed lightblue; /* this line is for demonstration purposes only */  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <dd>
        An introductory sentence as a text node.
        <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
      </dd>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <dd>
        <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
        <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
      </dd>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, what a terrible/terrific, wicked, wonderful answer. I wondered whether anything could be done using `before { content:` but I wasn't expecting that! It seems to actually answer the question; but I fear it's too abstruse, unexpected, to use in real code.

Comment: I have attempted to make this a little less abstruse (thanks for teaching me a new word :)) by proving that this pseudo element trickery really doesn't behave different than any other element would, but yes the ways of mixed block and line formatting contexts are mindbogglingly incomprehensible at times.

Answer (score 3):

#### First Answer:

It's permitted per current HTML spec (HTML5). However, the Strict flavors of previous generation of HTML (HTML4/XHTML1) required certain elements (e.g. `body` or `form`) to contain only blocks, not bare text or text level elements (now collectively referred as "phrasing content"). The newer spec had to relax this limitation in order to match reality, but I believe it had a rationale, primarily because of the next point...

#### Second Answer:

As Mathijs Flietstra said in his answer, any run of text placed in the same container as block level elements without any `display:block` wrapper ends up being the anonymous block box (because a CSS block can contain either inline boxes or block boxes, but not both kinds of them). These anonymous boxes are behave like usual block boxes (think `div` elements), but you can't set them any CSS property directly, they only get the inheritable properties from the container. So there is no way to set them neither padding nor margin nor border nor background. All existing CSS selectors just don't take them into account (except `:empty` pseudo class, but it isn't very helpful in this case).

Yes, sometimes you can find a hack to work around this limitation. Moreover, modern CSS mechanisms like Grid Layout provide ways, e.g., to have uniform spacing between chilren of the container regardless their type:

```css
div > * {
  margin:0;
}
div{
  display:grid;
  grid-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p>Another further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
  An introductory sentence as a text node.
  <p> A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <address>Another further sentence as an <code>address</code> element.</address>
</div>
```

However, neither of these workariunds is a silver bullet. For example, you can't apply `display:grid` to a table cell without breaking the table structure.

#### Third answer:

Given that CSS block can contain only one type of boxes and how problematic working with anonymous boxes can be, I'd say that the good rule of thumb would be the following:

> Never place a text node without a wrapper in the block where other blocks are supposed to appear.

Just `<li>Text</li>` is completely OK. But if the nested list is supposed to be added to this `<li>` at some point in the future, IMHO, it would be better to wrap the text in any element — at least just `<span>` (then you would be able to set it `display:block` and any block properties, if such need suddenly occurs).

Answer (score 0):

#### First answer:

**Yes**. The **[`<dd>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd)** and **[`<dt>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt)** elements both accept **[flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)**. That means that either a paragraph tag or raw text is perfectly acceptable. Paragraphs themselves don't breaks the flow, so you can have as many or as few as you would like.

#### Second answer:

You would use the **[:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** pseudo-selector:

```css
dd {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

dd > p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  <p>Sample text</p>
  <p>Sample text</p>
</dd>
```

This allows you to target the first occurrence of any specified selector (in this case, that's any `<p>` tag that's a direct child of a `<dd>` tag).

Because the pseudo-selector is relative to the `<p>` tag, this also works when the first element is **not** a `<p>` tag:

```css
dd {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

dd > p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  <strong>Bold text</strong>
  <p>Sample text</p>
  <p>Sample text</p>
</dd>
```

Also, note that the `<p>` tag itself has a predefined rule of `margin: 1em 0`, which you can override if you'd like the `<p>` tags to sit closer to one another.

#### Comment answer:

Keep in mind that `p:first-of-type` is targeting the first **`<p>`** tag. Text without a tag specified is considering to be part of the immediate parent (in this case `<dd>`, and by default `<body>`). Because you're only targeting the first `<p>` tag, if you would like margins between **both** the free text and the text contained within the second paragraph, you'll need to apply margins on **both** the top and bottom:

```css
dd {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

dd > p:first-of-type {
  margin: 5em 0;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  Free text
  <p>TARGETED text</p>
  <p>Paragraph text</p>
</dd>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Specifying `p { margin: 1em 0 }` with `dd > p:first-of-type { margin-top: 0; }` works in my second example (because it removes the margin from the first paragraph), but doesn't work in my first example (it doesn't place a margin between the two sentences).

Comment: @ChrisW -- I've updated my answer to cover your comment :)

Comment: I want a `margin-top` on the first `<p>` if-and-only-if it followed an initial text node (as in the first example), but I don't want a `margin-top` on the first `<p>` if there is no previous text node (as in the second example). That's my problem, and I don't see how your answer helps with that.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry, I misinterpreted that initially. You're essentially attempting to check for the presence of text that doesn't constitute an element. As such, there's unfortuntely [**no way**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) with raw CSS to check for its presence. The **only** edge-case would be checking `:empty` on the `<dd>`, though considering you're adding the `<p>` tag as well, the content will never be empty. I'm afraid you'll need to adjust your HTML structure or utilise JavaScript in order to check for the `<` character in the content.

Comment: If there's **no way** to do it in CSS, do you know how this problem is solved in practice? For example do web site authors choose, by convention, to always start a block (such as a `<td>` or `<dd>` or `<div>`) with a `<p>`, and never start one with an initial text node without a `<p>`?

Comment: Personally, if I used **at least one tag** inside a `<dd>`, I'd ensure that **every** individual component of `<dd>` contains a tag. That ensures consistency, and provides a nicer markup in my opinion. Often for raw text I end up just wrapping it inside a `<span>` tag if I need to target that specific piece of text. Having said that, you could first target the `<dd>` tag itself, give that the desired styling, then target all elements that are **not** the raw text (with just `dd > *` for example), and give them the **opposite** styling. That would have the same effect as targeting the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

**MODIFIED**

1) yes

2) no, <del>unless you prevent a text node from overflowing the width of a single line by keeping the first line brief.</del> not even a `<br>` will work.

**ADD**

'Free' floating (untagged) text does not seem to have any CSS selector available, which makes it impossible to select without use of Javascript. I remember having had the need for that. Call it a W3C omission?

The only possibility seemed to be the `:empty` selector but thusfar I have not been able to create some CSS logic that grasps a text node lingering before a tagged element. So that use looks bleak at best (assuming I know my logic...)

**end add**

In other cases, you could remove the HTML default `top-margin` given for free on several elements (see first line of CSS code) and add `td>:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem }` to give the second line a top margin.

```css
p,.or-any-element-with-HTML-default-margins {
    margin-top: 0;
}
td>:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
 
   /* demo, ignore */
   table,tr,td {
    border: 1px dotted silver;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 20rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>some table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>text node
                <p><strong>paragraph</strong> paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <p><strong>1st</strong> paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
                <p><strong>2nd</strong> paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><strong>paragraph</strong> paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
                Ordered List (<strong>text node</strong>)
                <ol>
                    <li>List item 1</li>
                    <li>List item 2</li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><strong>paragraph</strong> paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
                Unordered List (<strong>text node</strong>)
                <ul>
                    <li>List item 1</li>
                    <li>List item 2</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

3) not appropriate for SO. Thusly, my 2 cents stay in my pocket...

Comment: I think this only works because there are inline elements (which CSS sees as the "first child") )in the first sentence. If you use my first HTML example (the first sentence is a text node with `<p>` and no inline `<strong>`) then the `:not(:first-child)` rule wouldn't put a margin on the second sentence i.e. on the first and only `<p>`.

Comment: Been so busy with this, that I 'thought' I had tested that. Now I did and modded my answer to reflect my findings.

Comment: @ChrisW In the mean time this Q will remain to bug me the rest of the week no doubt. I hate loose ends, so I will surely get back at this.... Having said that, where is code the of all the work you have done on this so far? Retracable, reproducable and such.

Comment: It has bugged me for years. I'd think it should be a basic requirements: "margin between paragraphs". I'm surprised it doesn't seem to bug others, and wondered how other people cope. I haven't found (I don't know of) a pure CSS solution that will handle either style of HTML. So I discipline myself to write some standard (i.e. my standard) HTML. That doesn't seem to me an ideal solution though, if there were more than one author of a web site.

Comment: I am more a 'let go' or '3 times left is right too' kinda person. Having worked on assignment all of my career I have learned to get pragmatic when an hour of work costs a $100 or more. So, 'add an extra set of tags, no biggy'. At the end of the day contemplating my vacation destinations seem more rewarding, more health improving. But yes, hence my W3C remark. Then again, there are much more pressing CSS issues, I guess.

Comment: Sometimes I work on a project for a long time, so I'm interested in things which reduce friction: refactoring, and so on. If you add an extra set of tags today, you'll have to add another extra set of tags tomorrow too, and end up with a codebase full of extra tags, and HTML which isn't independent of the CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150461/discussion-between-rene-van-der-lende-and-chrisw).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this is acceptable. You can always check if your HTML is valid by using the W3C's markup validation service (https://validator.w3.org/).
2. I was able to accomplish this using `:last-child`. See the demo below. You can even give the `<td>` a narrow width for line-wrapping and see that it still works.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td > :last-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        An introductory sentence as a text node.
        <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
        <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using `:last-child` is a special case for two sentences. What if there are `n` sentences?

Comment: Is that a requirement? You specify multiple times in your question that there are two sentences, not any number of sentences.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't explicit. I want CSS that provides a margin between paragraphs, for any legal HTML. The fact that the first paragraph may or may not be a text node, and may or may not contain inline elements, makes that challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class for the element that should have a margin:

- Assign top margin
- Assign line height

Or use this to be specific, like the second child element:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
   top-margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**First Answer**: Its valid

**Second Answer**:

There is no way to differentiate between these two `<p>` elements with respect to parent (`<div>`)

Case1: WithText

```
<div>
  Hello
  <p> hi</p>
</div>
```

Case2:WithoutText

```
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

In both the case `<p>` is first child, last child etc..Every selector that will apply to WithText's `<p>` will also apply to WithoutText's `<p>`.

But still I tried...

When: Order is irrelevant (reverse-order) and container size is fix

```css
div p{
  margin:0 0 20px 0;
}
div{
  height:150px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: end;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>An introductory sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p>A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
  <p> An another further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
  An introductory sentence as a text node.
      <p> A further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
      <p> An another further sentence as a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**Third Answer:**

> Is this Impossible?

I dont know..

> Then I guess that web site authors must be careful to always use only
>   one HTML markup?

Consistency is good. But there are no rules here to force it.

> If so, which you do suppose it normal?

It depends...